# Batch script listing files in a directory by appending to string

Tags: windows, batch-file, string-concatenation

I am using a batch file and need to be able to list all JavaScript files found at a relative path to where the batch script is run. The final list needs to be formatted as:

```
"C:\path\to\file1.js" "C:\path\to\file2.js" "C:\path\to\file3.js" etc..
```

So far I have done:

```
SET files=""
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s ".\path\to\files\*.js"') DO (
    SET files=!files! "%%i"
)
ECHO Files found: %files%
```

However, with the script above, all I get as output is:

```
Files found: "" C:\path\to\last\file.js
```

It only outputs the last file that was found in the directory. I don't know what the issue is here as to why it only appends the last file.

Comment: You need to include `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning of your program

Comment: I have seen this in other questions, but it setting this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Batch file below exactly as appears here:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "files="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /s ".\path\to\files\*.js"') DO (
    SET files=!files! "%%i"
)
ECHO Files found: %files%
```

If the output is not what you want, execute the next command directly from the command-line:

```
dir /b /s ".\path\to\files\*.js"
```

If previous line show the same files than the Batch file, then the problem is related to `dir` command.